# Are the block producers shuffled between rounds in new hybrid DPoS + BFT

Tags: block-producer

Are the block producers shuffled between rounds in the new [hybrid DPoS + BFT](https://medium.com/eosio/dpos-bft-pipelined-byzantine-fault-tolerance-8a0634a270ba)?

Say there are 4 block producers.
Assume blocks are produced in the following order:

- t = 1: A
- t = 2: B
- t = 3: C
- t = 4: D

Are the producers shuffled in the new [hybrid DPoS + BFT](https://medium.com/eosio/dpos-bft-pipelined-byzantine-fault-tolerance-8a0634a270ba) system from t = 5 to 8 and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every 126 seconds the top 21 block producer by vote weight produce 12 blocks each in alphabetical order by EOS account.

You can see the code here: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/src/voting.cpp